# How To keep the Countdown timer ticking

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, timer

I am working on an app were i am using a countdown timer,my problem is that after every minute the timer stops and if i close or open the App again it ticks again and stops after one minute. the code for the timer is

```
 TimeSpan span2 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    TimeSpan span;
    private void tbkRemaningTime_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox text = sender as TextBox;
        TimeSpan.TryParse(text.Text, out span);


                if (span.Seconds > 0)
                {
                    span = span.Subtract(span2);
                    text.Text = span.ToString();
                }



    }

    private async void tbkRemaningTime_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
        TextBox text = sender as TextBox;
        TimeSpan.TryParse(text.Text, out span);

        if (span.Seconds > 0)
        {
            span = span.Subtract(span2);
            text.Text = span.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide your timer with matching 'Tick' Event?

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Threading.Timer:

```
TimerCallback oneMinuteElapsed = new TimerCallback(TimerHandler);
Timer timer1;
timer1 = new Timer(oneMinuteElapsed, "min1", 0, 1000*60);

private static void TimerHandler(object state)
{
      ...
}
```

The Ticker timer1 starts oneMinuteElapsed every minute and that calls the TimerHandler where you can put your code that shall be performed every minute.

the last parameter of Timer is the delay in millisecounds.
the parameter before this (here 0) defines when to start the ticking.

Comment: my another problem is as the timer starts ,the timer stops if i navigate from the timer page to another page and resume itself when i am back on the timer page in windows phone .how can i solve this problem..

Comment: I dont know about windows phone, but in webapplications there is a page called global.asax in which you can put code that is indipendent from the loaded site. Do you have any Application_Start Method in your windows phone application? This could be the right place for the timer.

Comment: the parameter min1 ,what it represent i did not understand i tried but its not working .My code is right but it fails in page navigation. help me out if it can be solved in another way and windows phone application do not contain any application_start method.

Comment: "min1" is just a string. Here it does not mean anything. I think it is there so you can pass information about the timer to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan.Seconds returns only the seconds portion of the TimeSpan - a value from -59 to 59.  You probably want to use TotalSeconds instead.

IOW, this code (in two places)

```
if (span.Seconds > 0)
{
    span = span.Subtract(span2);
    text.Text = span.ToString();
}
```

is going to stop doing anything after about 1 minute, because span.Seconds will be 0, even though span represents a much longer length of time.